# Change color of Buttons and textview on button click

Tags: java, android

I wan to make a feature for my application Written in Android Studio Java. The feature is that I want to allow users to change the color of the application that means the button colors, textbox colors etc. The Buttons, Textview etc of my apps are using custom drawable files like buttons are using "custom_button_ios_blue" and textviews are using "custom_text_view_ios_blue" now I want to make this feature like when a user clicks on Change Theme Orange button, all the buttons and textview using these custom drawable xml files should now use "custom_button_ios_orange" and "custom_text_view_ios_orange" files and it should retain that chosen file whenever the app starts.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this example from Medium for setting up dynamic themes to android app.

[Implementing Dynamic Theming in Android](https://medium.com/@nihitb06.dev/implementing-dynamic-theming-in-android-a9ed4f5010a8)